# Reading value of variable in javascript find

Tags: javascript, arrays

I try to read the value of the key color_ids in the following JavaScript  associative array:

```
  const UrlArray = [
    {
      bd_shoe_size_ids: ["6601", "6598"]
    },
    {
      color_ids: ["6056", "6044"]
    },
    {
      manufacturer_ids: ["5875", "5866"]
    }
  ]
```

This was done by the following code:

```
UrlArray.find(({color_ids}) => color_ids);
```

But I would like to use this code for reading the value of other array keys to. For that I want to store the name of the array key whose value I want to know in a variable.
If I use the code below it will of course look for a key called nameOfArrayKey, but is it possible to search for the value of the variable: nameOfArrayKey?

```
UrlArray.find(({nameOfArrayKey}) => nameOfArrayKey);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Try this:

```
console.log(UrlArray.map(Object.keys).flat())
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use hasOwnProperty property to check object has key name

```js
function getObject(urlArray,nameKey){
  const object= urlArray.find(value=>{
     return value.hasOwnProperty(nameKey)
  });
  return object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, you can try something like this :

```js
const k = "manufacturer_ids"
console.log(UrlArray.find((o) => o[k]))
```

Output :

```js
{ manufacturer_ids: [ '5875', '5866' ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getObjectValueByKey (items, key) {
  const item = items.find(value => value.hasOwnProperty(key));
  
  if (item) {
    return item[key];
  }

  return null
}

const values = getObjectValueByKey(UrlArray, 'color_ids') // ['6056', '6044']
```